# How can I use the Platform LSF blaunch command to start processes simultaneously?

Tags: bash, lsf

I'm having a hard time figuring out why I can't launch commands in parallel using the LSF `blaunch` command:

```
for num in `seq 3`; do
blaunch -u JobHost ./cmd_${num}.sh &
done
```

Error message:

```
Oct 29 13:08:55 2011 18887 3 7.04 lsb_launch(): Failed while executing tasks.
Oct 29 13:08:55 2011 18885 3 7.04 lsb_launch(): Failed while executing tasks.
Oct 29 13:08:55 2011 18884 3 7.04 lsb_launch(): Failed while executing tasks.
```

Removing the ampersand (`&`) allows the commands to execute sequentially, but I am after parallel execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executed within the context of bsub, a single invocation of `blaunch -u <hostfile> <cmd>` will take `<cmd>` and run it on all the hosts specified in `<hostfile>` in parallel as long as those hosts are within the job's allocation.

What you're trying to do is use 3 separate invocations of `blaunch` to run 3 separate commands.  I can't find it in the documentation, but just some testing on a recent version of LSF shows that each individually executed task in such a job has a unique task ID stored for it in an environment variable called LSF_PM_TASKID.  You can verify this in your version of LSF by running something like:

```
blaunch -I -n <num_tasks> blaunch env | grep TASKID
```

Now, what does this have to do with your question?  You want to run `./cmd_$i.sh` for i=1,2,3 in parallel through `blaunch`.  To do this you can write a single script which I'll call `cmd.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
./cmd_${LSF_PM_TASKID}.sh
```

Now you can replace your for loop with a single invocation of `blaunch` like so:

```
blaunch -u JobHost cmd.sh
```

This will run one instance of `cmd.sh` on each host listed in the file 'JobHost' *in parallel*, each of these instances will run the shell script `cmd_X.sh` where `X` is the value of `$LSF_PM_TASKID` for that particular task.

If there's exactly 3 hostnames in 'JobHost' then you will get 3 instances of `cmd.sh` which will in turn lead to one instance each of `cmd_1.sh`, `cmd_2.sh`, and `cmd_3.sh`

Comment: Finally I have an answer to my question! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `nohup`? This might work:

```
for num in `seq 3`; do
nohup blaunch -u JobHost ./cmd_${num}.sh &>/dev/null &
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`blaunch` is not to be used outside of the job execution environment provided by `bsub`. I don't know how to handle running different commands for each process, but try something like:

```
bsub -n 3 blaunch ./cmd.sh
```

Comment: The call to blaunch is made under the bsub environment. Perhaps I didn't make that clear in the question